# Infinite loop in Material UI onSortModelChange(React js)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Documentation: https://v4.mui.com/components/data-grid/sorting/#data-grid-sorting

```
const [sortModel, setSortModel] = React.useState([
{
  field: 'name',
  sort: 'asc',
},]);

const columns = [
{ field: 'name' },
{ field: 'school'}]

const rows = [
{ id: 1, name: 'React', school: 'abc' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Material-UI', school: 'pqr' },]

<DataGrid
 columns={columns}
 rows={rows}
 sortingOrder={['desc', 'asc']}
 sortModel={sortModel}
 onSortModelChange={(model) => setSortModel(model)}
  />
```

Clicking on the sort button causes infiite loop

Comment: `onSortModelChange={handleSo}` what does this function `handleSo` do

Comment: ohh sorry, Thats a typo. I've edited it now.

Comment: What is the specific error message/feedback that tells you it's an infinite loop? React error messages are usually pretty helpful.

Comment: It crashes and the button keeps alternating b/w ascending and descending on it's own and the data in console keep rendering. There is one error which says minimun limit reached and the rendering continues I tried the same with the latest version of material UI(5.2.3), it works fine there. But the one I'm working on uses material version 4.

Comment: It sounds to me like `onSortModelChange` is triggered when you pass in a new `sortModel` property. Do you need to update the data in the parent if the child component is doing the sorting? (Perhaps try just commenting out the `onSortModelChange` and see what happens)

Comment: Yes, onSortModelChange is triggered when we pass sortModel. Im supposed to make the first column sort to be set to 'descending' when the browser loads and only onSortModelChange can solve that according to the documentation. When I comment onSortModelChange, the sort button doesn't work and when I comment sortModel it returns to default sort order(null,asc,desc)

Comment: Have tried running your code and it seems to work; can you post the rest of your code? Seems like it might be something else that's causing the issue.